# How to iterate or get a list of all input parameters in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

This works:

```
Get-Command $PSCommandPath | %{ $_.Parameters }
```

But this doesn't:

```
Get-Command $PSCommandPath | %{ $_.Parameters | %{ echo $_.Value } }
```

Why?

Comment: I am confused on what you are trying to accomplish? You want to pipe the results into another where statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Parameters property is a hash table (dictionary):

```
Get-Command $PSCommandPath | %{ $_.Parameters.GetType() }


IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                              
True     True     Dictionary`2                             System.Object
```

The Powershell pipeline will automatically "unroll" arrays and collections, but not hash tables.  If you want to `foreach`through the indivudual elements, you have to enumerate them expliclitly using `.getenumerator()`.

```
Get-Command $PSCommandPath | %{ $_.Parameters.GetEnumerator() | % {echo $_.Value } }
```

Comment: Yea! almost there.. but this: `echo $_.Value.ToString()` emits: `System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata` instead of the parameter string value.. how can I output the parameter's text?

Comment: and ` %{ foreach($i in $_.Parameters.GetEnumerator()) { echo $i.Value.ToString() } }` gives the same: `System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata`

Comment: Define "the parameter's text".

Comment: ok, got it: `Get-Command $PSCommandPath | %{ $_.Parameters.GetEnumerator() | % { (Get-Variable $_.Key).Value } }`